# Cannot install npm packages on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have installed node.js and npm on ubuntu using aptitude but when i try to install any package like socket.io for example i get the warnings below:

```
username@server:~$ npm install socket.io
/home/username
└── socket.io@1.7.3

    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/username/package.json'
    npm WARN username No description
    npm WARN username No repository field.
    npm WARN username No README data
    npm WARN username No license field.
```

**Running**:

- Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- npm v4.4.4
- Node.js v4.2.6

Anyone with any good ideas?

Comment: does `package.json` exists in that directory?

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. The package got installed okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows just warning not error, your package got installed in `node_modules`.

> It's best practice to create `package.json` always in root folder to install all required modules.

The warning also make sense, try to find `package.json` in `/home/username/package.json`

You can create `package.json` by command

> `npm init`

follow the step during creation of pakcage.json